# What is the correct translation for 'brewing potion'?

Tags: traduction

I'm doubting about the correct translation of

> brewing potion

I hesitate between 'brassage des potions' and 'potions de brassage'.
Is there any difference?

Comment: What is the *context*? "Brewing potion" isn't quite clear. Potion for brewing? The process of brewing potion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both could be correct, with a little stretch of imagination

- “*Potions de brassage.*” would be potions that help brewing things.

  > *Le secret des trappistes ? Ils boivent des potions de brassage avant d'aller travailler !*

  or (thanks @YohannnV.)

  > *Potion de brassage : Mélanger cette potion à n'importe quel aliment pour en faire un alcool plutôt corsé !*
- “*Brassage des potions*” would rather be “Potion brewing”, that is, the activity of brewing potions.

  > *C'est quoi le cours suivant, Hermione ? Brassage des potions !*

That said, *brassage* is pretty specific to beer, so it would probably be better to find another verb, e.g. “*Fabrication des potions*”.

Following @YohannnV.'s comment: if your source phrase is indeed “brewing potion” (singular), it could translate as either “*potion de brassage*” (see above) or “*une potion en cours de brassage*” (a potion that is currently brewing), but not as “*brassage des potions*” since in that case *potions* is generic and therefore can't be singular.

Comment: Pourquoi le pluriel? Il n'y a pas de 's' à *"brewing potion"*

Comment: « *I hesitate between 'brassage des potions' and 'potions de brassage'* »

Comment: **Potion de brassage** : Mélanger cette potion à n'importe quel aliment pour en faire un alcool plutôt corsé ! ooooor **I'm *brewing potion...*** : Je suis en train de brasser une potion... It strongly depends of context.

Comment: I don't agree with the second one: that would be “I'm brewing **a** potion.”.

Comment: TY so much, this was an amazing explanation!

Comment: @Evpok I just wanted to underline that OP didn't put an 's' so we needed more context to elaborate. But it seems you answered to his questions without it, well done ! *Thanks for adding my comment in answer* ;)

Comment: I'm sorry, can we actually say '“Fabrication des potions” in French?

Comment: @wibble Yeah, why not ?

Answer (score 1):

'potions de brassage' does not mean anything in French. 'brassage des potions' can make sense but it really depends on the context.